# Two tangents to a curve intersecting at a point

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, tangent-line

Q) find the equations of the tangent lines to the curve $y=x^3+x$ which pass through point $(2,2)$

**my attempt**: I tried to formulating two equations for both tangents and then inserting the values 2,2 in them.After that I tried to solve these equations but there were too many unknowns and little equations

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If those curves are *tangent* to the curve, their slope is given by $\;y'=3x^2+1\;$ at each general point $\;(x,\,x^3+x)\;$ on the curve , so for what points $\;(a,\,a^3+a)\;$ **on the curve** are there lines through them *and* through $\;(2,2)\;$ whose slope is $\;3a^2+1\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:
1) The slope of the tangent is the value of the derivative of the function at a given point. 
2) Any line can be expressed in point-slope form.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the tangent at point $(a,a^3+a)$ contains the point $(2,2)$.

We know that the slope of the line is

$$m=3a^2+1$$

but we also know that the slope of the line is

$$ m=\frac{a^3+a-2}{a-2} $$

therefore

$$ \frac{a^3+a-2}{a-2}=3a^2+1 $$

which simplifies to

$$ 2a^2(a-3)=0 $$

So either $a=0$ or $a=3$ giving $m=1$ or $m=28$.

1. \begin{eqnarray}
   y-2&=&x-2\\
   y&=&x
   \end{eqnarray}
2. \begin{eqnarray}
   y-2&=&28(x-2)\\
   y&=&28x-54
   \end{eqnarray}